# how to solve/fix this issue throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function') when starts the server in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am facing this issue when trying to run server after create route and use route in app.js file.Please help me to resolve the error i have been stuck here for hours tried a lot of edits but its not working for me.

**Here is my courseRoute.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Course = require('../../models/Course');
const adminAuthMiddleware = require('../../middleware/adminAuthMiddleware');

router.get('/admin/view-course', adminAuthMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Course.find((err, docs) => {
            if (!err) {
                res.render('admin-views/course/view_course', { courses: docs });
            } else {
                res.send('Error in retrieving Course list :' + err);
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
});
```

**This is my app.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const path = require('path');
require('./db/conn');

const courseRoute = require('./routes/admin routes/courseRoute');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const static_path = path.join(__dirname, "../public");

app.use(express.static(static_path));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false }));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(courseRoute);


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Your `courseRoute.js` has no exports, so `const courseRoute = require('./routes/admin routes/courseRoute');` results in `courseRoute` being `undefined`. You probably wanted to [export](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules_commonjs_modules) a middleware from from it (or not use `app.use(courseRoute)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your courseRoute.js has no exports. In the last line add module.export = route;